# How do I write a function for this dojo widget

Tags: javascript, dojo

I just created this dojo widget and now I want to attached an event to it can I see how it is done:

```
var filteringSelect = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
        id: "test",
    },
    "test");
```

I want to attached an onfocus function to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- [FilteringSelect API Documentation](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/api/dijit/form/FilteringSelect.html) (for the doc on its onFocus handler)
- [dojo.connect API](http://api.dojotoolkit.org/jsdoc/1.2/dojo.connect) and [dojo.connect Campus](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/connect)

It's pretty much all you need to read.

EDIT: you might find this [introductory tutorial to Dojo and Dijit](http://www.projectzero.org/sMash/1.1.x/docs/zero.devguide.doc/zero.hellodojo.demo/HelloDojoTutorial.html) useful, especially this sample.

EDIT2: To be more specific, all you need to do is:

```
dojo.connect(dijit.byId("ID_OF_YOUR_WIDGET"), "onBlur" , yourCallBackFunctionAndBeCarefulWithScoping);
```

Comment: Note for those reading this that since dojo 1.7 it uses AMD loader and not dojo connect any more

Answer (score 0):

```
var filteringSelect = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
    id: "test",
onFocus :function(){/*handler for onFocus */}
},
"test");
```

Note the CAPITAL F in onFocus, if you use onfocus things wont work.